# Android how to download video using playlist id from rss feed

Tags: android, video, xml-parsing, rss

I want to download videos from each episode from the following rss feed

```
http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsVideo
```

From this xml, I can get each episode's title, description and link. I don't know that how to retrieve video from that link. I want to download those videos in my Sdcard.

My Problem is:

How to get videos from that link of episode?

**EDIT**

I found out [this xml](http://playlists.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-22797866A/playlist.sxml)(playlist) from one of the [html](http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/54mvYKrBLZA/) of above [link](http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsVideo).

I have given that playlist Xml below:

```
<playlist revision="1">
<id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:22793516</id>
<title>Where Guantanamo's hunger strike began </title>
<summary>The BBC's Jonathan Beale takes a tour of Guantanamo Bay, where more than 100 detainees are now on hunger strike. </summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-22793516"/>
<link rel="holding" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/68007000/jpg/_68007602_68007601.jpg" width="640" height="360" type="image/jpeg"/>
<published>2013-06-06T04:04:39Z</published>
<updated>2013-06-06T05:49:47Z</updated>
<config>
<settings> <setting name="language">en</setting> </settings>
<plugin name="fmtjLiveStats">
<param name="siteId">News</param>
<param name="uniqueId">22793516</param>
<param name="parentSection">99127</param>
</plugin>
</config>
<rights><!-- Blocked for 3rd party embedding. --><right name="embed">blocked</right></rights>
<item kind="advert">
<id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:advert:mediaAsset:22793516</id>
<media kind="video" width="640" height="360" type="video/mp4">
<connection kind="doubleClick" companionSize="$companionSize" companionType="$companionType" companionId="$companionId" href="$preroll"/>
</media>
</item>
<item kind="ident">
<id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:ident:news:video:640x360</id>
<media kind="video" width="640" height="360" type="video/mp4">
<connection kind="akamai" identifier="public/flash/ident/news" server="cp45414.edgefcs.net"/>
</media>
</item>
<item kind="programme" duration="130" identifier="22793516" group="p01b18l6"><id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:mediaAsset:22793516</id><mediator identifier="p01b18l6" name="pips"/>
</item>
<!-- related links --><relatedLink><id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:22349190</id>
<title>Guantanamo Bay detentions explained</title>
<summary>American authorities have sent extra medical staff to the Guantanamo detention camp to help deal with a growing hunger strike by its inmates.</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-22349190"/>
<link rel="thumb" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/67316000/jpg/_67316425_09fe0d5b-c5b3-4a17-b884-34f6591b24e8.jpg" width="112" height="63" type="image/jpeg"/>
</relatedLink>
<relatedLink>
<id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:22649505</id>
<title>Obama heckled over Guantanamo Bay</title>
<summary>US President Barack Obama is heckled over his failure to close the Guantanamo Bay prison by a member of the audience during a national security speech.</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-22649505"/>
<link rel="thumb" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/67787000/jpg/_67787465_67786949.jpg" width="112" height="63" type="image/jpeg"/>
</relatedLink>
<relatedLink>
<id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:22361550</id>
<title>Obama renews vow to close Guantanamo</title>
<summary>US President Barack Obama pledges a new push to close the prison at Guantanamo Bay, Cuba, amid a growing prisoner hunger strike there.</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-22361550"/>
<link rel="thumb" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/67338000/jpg/_67338544_67338442.jpg" width="112" height="63" type="image/jpeg"/>
</relatedLink>
<relatedLink><id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:22249470</id>
<title>Guantanamo Bay hunger strike spreads</title>
<summary>A US military spokesman says that 84 of the 166 prisoners at Guantanamo Bay are now on hunger strike, but none have life-threatening conditions.</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-22249470"/>
<link rel="thumb" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/67165000/jpg/_67165552_aptn_guantanamo.jpg" width="112" height="63" type="image/jpeg"/>
</relatedLink>
<relatedLink>
<id>tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:20730083</id>
<title>Guantanamo inmate sues government</title>
<summary>A man detained at Guantanamo Bay whose family live in south-west London has started a defamation suit against the UK security and intelligence services.</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-20730083"/>
<link rel="thumb" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/64779000/jpg/_64779275_64774165.jpg" width="112" height="63" type="image/jpeg"/>
</relatedLink>
</playlist>
```

Is there any way to download video using this playlist id(`tag:bbc.co.uk,2008:cps:playlist:mediaAsset:22793516`) in android?

I refer this [link](http://www.rsshandler.com/converter) to change download video using this playlist id.

Please help me! Or give any idea to achieve it!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that simple. I have studied the CBS RSS link and it's not designed to allow direct downloading of video. It's designed to provide a link that a user can follow and land on the website where they can view the video on a web page. It is still theoretically possible to download the video automatically, but not at all straightforward. A program would have to resolve the link, download the HTML, parse the HTML and extract intelligence about the video file from the embedded values surrounding the Flash-based video player found in the page. Then, assuming the data could be downloaded via raw HTTP, figure out the direct video URL and download the video.

Anything is possible; just depends on how much effort you care to exert.